# Update backbone.js collection without re-rendering the template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, d3.js

Say I have five ranks, and different data points about each rank (salary, number, average, etc.). I build a collection of models, one model for each rank.

Then I have a Rank view and an App view - rendering down five Rank views inside my App view. I also need to put a d3 chart inside each one of those rank views.

SO far, no problems. But then I choose a button, update my collection with new data, and I have to re-render each Rank view to display the new data in my collection, correct? Re-rendering the data would rebuild the d3 chart each time, which I don't want to do, because I want the chart to have transitions.

Can anyone give me a little guidance? Not code necessarily, just possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply update values and re-animate them at will.  There's no need to fully destroy the object and create a new one, though that's a shortcut you see taken often because it is scary simple....but it also introduces display issues at the same time.

Here's a simple example of changing values of a table and re-animating instead of destroying and making new:  [D3 redraw example](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7030f35b72de721622b8)  You obviously get your data very differently via Backbone models, but the concepts are the same.

I have a similar pattern as you in my lighting control app, and I really have grown fond of using a grid to render the collection, with links to open each of the individual views, whether via a link to a new page (my preferred method) or a modal (the bosses' favorite method)  My current grid of choice is [Backgrid.js](http://backgridjs.com/) which is tied directly to the collection and therefore requires no work at all to update on model change.